# How to make a group of labels to align themselves in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, layout

Im relatively new to iOS development, and my constraints skill is at a basic level. I'm having a group of labels like so

[image]

However the **Company Name** and **Address Line 2** are not always required so they are hidden in some cases, but when they are I don't know how to push the other labels up so that they fill the space created by the hidden labels.

Much appreciated if you guys can give a solution on this.

Comment: have you trid using stack view & manipulate constraints to do so

Comment: @Geet How can I do so, could you give me a reference?

Comment: Try this one : https://www.raywenderlich.com/160646/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views-2

Comment: StackView will be the best approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using constraints then for instance the top label should have leading, trailing and top to superview.

Now this label will have its height depending on its font and text. If its text is empty then its height will be zero which you basically want.

Now next label is best to have leading and trailing to superview (or the label above it) and then vertical spacing to label before it. This means it will be just below the first one. And if first one has no text it will be on top.

Now do the same for all other labels one blow the other using vertical offset constraint.

Note for what you are doing it seems more appropriate to use an `UITableView` or maybe stack view. But if you want constraints then this is the procedure.

If things get complicated you can also drag constraints into your code and manipulate them manually.. For instance:

```
self.companyNameHeightConstraint.constant = myDataMode.companyName.isEmpty == true ? 0.0 : 50.0
```

EDIT: Since it is a bit unclear if fields are displayed depending on some external flags or if these strings are shown if they exist I am adding a minimum table view procedure with external flags:

```
@interface TableViewController () <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *lastName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *companyName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *address1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *address2;

@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL isAddress2Shown;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL isCompanyNameShown;

@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (NSArray *)generateDsiaplyableStrings {
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if(self.name) [array addObject:self.name];
    if(self.lastName) [array addObject:self.lastName];
    if(self.companyName && self.isCompanyNameShown) [array addObject:self.companyName];
    if(self.address1) [array addObject:self.address1];
    if(self.address2 && self.isAddress2Shown) [array addObject:self.address2];
    return array;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self generateDsiaplyableStrings].count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSArray *items = [self generateDsiaplyableStrings];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:nil];
    cell.textLabel.text = items[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: Thing is this is one cell of an UITableView, does this fact affect anything?

Comment: @Joel No, it should not. If you add a bottom constraint for the bottom label to superview then the cell will size automatically if you use automatic dimensions. To make things easier simply set the bottom constraint priority to 900 (don't ask). But in your case would it not make more sense to put this in a section and each field is a new row rather then putting it all in a single cell?

Answer (score 2):

HI Joel why don't you try stack view inside table view cell and set

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

and stackview and tableview will handle everything for you.